# Classifying users in one of two groups

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, accuracy, train

I've a - probably beginner level - question about classifying. My goal is to classify users as UG1 or UG2, based on some specific characteristics of them. So, what I've done so far is:

1. I have two major groups of users (UG1 and UG2). Each study participant (N=67) took a test, and based on their total performance they were classified in these two groups (UG1 and UG2)
2. The test consists of five different types of questions (q1, q2, q3, q4, and q5), and after the analysis of the answer to each question type, I observed that the participants of UG1 and UG2 had significant differences in q4 and q5 question types (with .013 and 0.008 p level accordingly).
3. My hypothesis is that based on these findings I can develop a classifier based on the metrics that the two groups differ significantly (q4 and q5).
4. 51 more participants took part in the study, and I want to test if the classifier will classify them correctly (in one of the two groups).

So, I guess that the first participants (and their q4 and q5 answers) will be used as the training data; and then I'll do the validation. Is that correct?

My questions are:

1. How can I build the classifier?
2. How can I test the performance/accuracy of the classifier?

Comment: Regarding the classifier, you could use the most simple naive Bayes classifier. Knowing P(UG1), P(UG2), P(q4=x,q5=y | UG1) and P(q4=x,q5=y | UG2), use Bayes' theorem to predict P(UG1 | q4=x,q5=y) and PUG2 | q4=x,q5=y)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the first group as your training data. This is more rigorous than the norm (the norm is to randomly allocate cases into observed versus training data). It is more rigorous as inevitably there will be some aspect of the experimental condition that has changed. It would not be appropriate to use random allocation now, as you have already investigated the properties of your data.

There is no shortage of models. I suspect that the most common model in this situation, by a large margin, is the binary logit model.

You create a *confusion matrix*, which is a contingency table showing the observed groups by the predicted groups. The measures you will typically look at include: (a) The percentage accurate in the validation sample versus the estimation sample; and  (b) the extent to which the model predicts either group well (e.g., if one group is bigger than another, you can get a high overall accuracy by just predicting that all cases are in the bigger group).

Comment: Thanks Tim! What is still confusing to me is how can I "transfer" the knowledge I gained from the observations to a classification formula. I guess that the classification formula should be based on the observations, so shouldn't I introduce the p-value of each metric (q4 and q5) somehow (they're both derived from t-tests)? I've used Weka toolkit to classify the new data according to the supplied test-set (observations), and I get a good level of accuracy (the samples are balanced) but I still don't get how the significant differences observed influence the classifier. Hope it makes sense.